# How to download in-memory file object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, file

I have an in-memory file object like this in Javascript:

```
{
    name: "1_mRf78VMrVHjBMQpz6PYmiw.jpeg",
    lastModified: 1549023843303,
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Feb 01 2019 17:54:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
    webkitRelativePath: "",
    size: 265437,
}
```

How can I download it?

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.download =element.artifactName;//file name
link.href = element.artifact;//file object
link.click();
```

It is downloading corrupted file instead of original file.

Comment: You need to create an object URL out of your File instance first, and assign that as the link href. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm.

Comment: Please add the actual solution below for everyone to benefit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
var file = element.artifact;

link.download = element.artifactName;
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had difficulty following your solution. I was able to come up with this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = 'right.png';
a.click();
```

Where the `file` on line 2 is a reference to the file object.